# The space in between some sentences should not be removed while removing white space .by using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

### Situation:

I have to remove the special characters and white spaces from a file. The Whitespaces between the sentence quotes should not be removed. Only the white spaces leading the string and trailing the string needs to be removed.

### Input:

I am keeping my input as text format in between `{}`

```
{" fakldjfqllewfllwefklwdkf wefw "  ,XCSLDKVNADUFHef328E498234750139458YefA88787     ,"&*%&*^*&^()*)(*(*T&*UKLKJGYTDUJ:"                ,LMKCXXBJIUY&*(efewfqerfqerrferrferfeffgfadfgafegkEJFGI}
```

### The Powershellcode I tried to solve this:

```
$objFile1 = Get-Content "D:\my-training\powershell\Sample_file.csv"

foreach($line in $objFile1)
{
  $String = "$line"
  $value= $String -replace '[^\p{L}\p{Nd}/"/,]', ''
  Add-Content -path "D:\my-training\powershell\result.csv" -value $value 
}
```

### Output:

I am keeping my output as text format in between `{}`

```
{"fakldjfqllewfllwefklwdkfwefw",XCSLDKVNADUFHef328E498234750139458YefA88787,"TUKLKJGYTDUJ",LMKCXXBJIUYefewfqerfqerrferrferfeffgfadfgafegkEJFGI}
```

### Expected Output:

```
{"fakldjfqllewfllwefklwdkf  wefw",XCSLDKVNADUFHef328E498234750139458YefA88787,"TUKLKJGYTDUJ",LMKCXXBJIUYefewfqerfqerrferrferfeffgfadfgafegkEJFGI}
```

### Problem:

The problem is, that the code also deletes the whitespaces in the strings itself, I only want the leading and trailing whitespaces to be cut.

Comment: Please post the actual output (as text) rather than screenshots

Comment: To cut the trailing and leading whitespaces of an string, just use `Trim` like this `$String.Trim(" ")`.

Comment: my Actual input is  {" fakldjfqllewfllwefklwdkf wefw " ,XCSLDKVNADUFHef328E498234750139458YefA88787   ,"&*%&*^*&^()*)(*(*T&*UKLKJGYTDUJ:"               ,LMKCXXBJIUY&*(efewfqerfqerrferrferfeffgfadfgafegkEJFGI}

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Once check the post I have posted please check it and see if you could help me

Comment: @Paxz $String.Trim(" ") This will work if the whole string is in between the double quotes but my string is different case . once check my string i have posted in text format

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is certainly a strange looking string..
Anyway, this may do the trick for you:

```
$text = '{" fakldjfqllewfllwefklwdkf wefw "  ,XCSLDKVNADUFHef328E498234750139458YefA88787     ,"&*%&*^*&^()*)(*(*T&*UKLKJGYTDUJ:"                ,LMKCXXBJIUY&*(efewfqerfqerrferrferfeffgfadfgafegkEJFGI}'

# first remove the outer curly brackets and trim what is left
$text = $text -creplace '^\{\s*|\s*\}$', ''

# This regex will split comma separated lists of optionally quoted strings.
# It handles quoted delimiters ("") and escaped quotes(\"). 
# Whitespace inside quotes is preserved, outside is destroyed.
$regex = '(?m)\s*,\s*(?!(?<=(?:^|,)\s*"(?:[^"]|""|\\")*,\s*)(?:[^"]|""|\\")*"\s*(?:,|$))'
$parts = $text -split $regex

# output the text with whitespaces trimmed for strings within quotes
# enclose the whole thing again in curly brackets.
'{{{0}}}' -f 
(($parts | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -cmatch '^".*"$') {               # if the string is quoted
        $_ -creplace '^"\s*|\s*"$', '"'      # remove the whitespaces left and right of the actual string
    }
    else { $_ }                              # unquoted strings can pass as-is
}) -join ',')                                # join the parts with the comma as delimiter
```

outputs

```
{"fakldjfqllewfllwefklwdkf wefw",XCSLD;KVNADUFHef328E498234750139458YefA88787,"&*%&*^*&^()*)(*(*T&*UKLKJGYTDUJ:",LMKCXXBJIUY&*(efewfqerfqerrferrferfeffgfadfgafegkEJFGI}
```